# How to use iOS Carthage with TeamCity?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, teamcity, carthage

I need to up TeamCity CI/CD for my iOS project. I'm using Carthage for dependency management.

I understood that performing `carthage update` for each build is a bad idea. A build-agent will be rebuilding frameworks for every new build. It's very time-consuming operation.

Is there any approach for the caching my dependencies for speedup a build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible approach would be setting up a separate build configuration (e.g.,"Producer") that executes `carthage update` (whenever needed), then uploads zipped `Carthage/Build` to build server. Other build configurations for your project should have an artifact dependency on "Producer" and fetch binaries back to `Carthage/Build`

Comment: This approach is described in Fastlane documentation also.
[Speeding up build times with carthage](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#bamboo-integration)

Comment: If the package is already built and you can just pull that (as opposed to building them yourself on the build machine), then you can check in your Carthage.resolved files and just use carthage bootstrap to pull them. This may not work in your situation, but I thought I'd add this comment in case it helps you or someone else.